# American English pronunciation

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

As a non-native English Speaker, I'm studying connected speech and how words link in American English. However, I've got a little bit confused.
My American English Accent book explains that we must link consonants sounds to vowels sounds.
One example is: "Well, it's not working out between us."
The book only links the words "working" and "out". However, following the consonant sounds + vowel sounds rule, I would link the words "between" and "us", since according to the Cambridge dictionary their IPA transcription are respectively "/bɪˈtwiː**n**/" and "/****ʌ****s/ or /**ə**s/", in US English.
Should it be a typo or is there any special rule or exception for not linking them?

Comment: You are fairly perceptive.  But there's even more:  "It's not" gets run together into "it snot" as well.  And, actually, "working out" has less connection than the others.  In practice the words tend to be run together when the mouth position doesn't change much between the end of the first word and the start of the second.  (I suspect this is true of many other languages as well.)

Comment: There really aren't any spacesbetweenwords. That's part of the mythology of writing. Speech is continuous, for the most part. And sounds run together because that's the way the mouth and tongue and lips and larynx and nose and lungs work together. Every language has characteristic patterns; American English is a sitting target because (a) it's pretty uniform continent-wide (unlike English Englishes) (b) it's widely known from media (c) its native speakers are almost always totally clueless about their language or its pronunciation.

Comment: @HotLicks thank you very much for your comment. Since, you mentioned connected speech intensity, should I assume that it is related to the presence of content words? For example, I would separate the previous sentence into two thought groups, they are: "Well, it's not working out // between us." The content words would be: "working", "out" and "us". Aditionally, "out" (the last content word of the first thought group) and "us" would be the stressed words. Therefore, "it snot" would be strongly connected and "working out" and "between us" weakly connected. Are content words weakly connected?

Comment: Connections are controlled to a degree by pauses, and pauses tend to occur between words that are not closely related in "train of thought" that structures the sentence.  For instance, one of the longest pauses occurs between sentences.  But in your example sentence there's no real "thought grouping" (as you phrase it) and no pausing to speak of.  There is a break between "out" and "between" primarily because the mouth must change position between the end of "out" and the start of "between".

Comment: English English. Tempting to see this as a 'the real thing' reduplication. But as John Lawler says, there are more than one.